# Will iOS App Review allow apps having sign-in option without registration phase?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I develop an app related to a website. I would like to submit the app with only sign-in option and no registration. I first submitted app with a button which takes user to browser to register on website but it was rejected since it is bad UX and I am told that registration must be done inside app rather than taking user to browser.

What I want to know is whether it is allowed when there is no registration option at all? Or if it is mandatory to complete registration process inside app, is it fine to handle it inside a WebView?

I know that starting 30 June 2022, I have to offer another option as [deleting the account](https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app/) beside registration. That is what I am trying to avoid. We are not against deleting option but it is not ready yet and may be implemented later if it is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

Im my experience, an application that only allows sign-in to an existing account (that was already created in a separate process), without the option to create a new account, CAN pass AppStore review, As long as you provide a demo account for the reviewers to test.

Comment: Thanks. That is the exact case for me. I provide a demo account. I will try to send it to review today and share the result later.

Comment: Hi! I would like to know it is worked? I have a same process idea, so I would like to know it is approved or not? Thanks.

Comment: I also would like to know if it worked. Please let us know.